# Jsoup select elements that their children do not contain a specific tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to extract links from a web page, but i want to avoid img links.
so the following code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(i_Url).userAgent("chrome/5.0").get();
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
```

will get me all the links, but some of them are images. doing the following:

```
links.stream().filter(link -> !link.tagName().equals("img"));
```

won't work because the element's (=link) **child** is the one with the img tag, for instance:

```
<a href="index.htm" title="tutorialspoint">
  <img alt="tutorialspoint" src="/java/images/logo.png">
</a>
```

I tried all sorts of things, such as:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]").select(":not(img)"); //or
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]:not(img)"); //or
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]")
links.stream().filter(link -> link.children().contains(Tag.valueOf("img")));
```

I just tried to play with all kinds of variations, none of them worked. I'm not a big expert when it comes to html.
Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following selector:

```
a[href]:not(:has(img))
```

I have just tested it with following unit test, works like a charm:

```
@Test
public void testParsingLinksWithoutImagesInside() {
    //given:
    String html = "<a href=\"index.htm\" title=\"tutorialspoint\">\n" +
            "  <img alt=\"tutorialspoint\" src=\"/java/images/logo.png\">\n" +
            "</a>";

    //when:
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements elements = document.select("a[href]:not(:has(img))");

    //then:
    assertThat(elements.size()).isEqualTo(0);
}
```

I hope it helps :)